Why is python 3.9 being used by my rpi bullseye OS for this envirophat pimoroni project?
i installed bullseye 32 bit on my rpi2 and installed the envirphat board on the pin header.  I used to have the same envirphat board on a rpi0 that unfortunately got wet.
I installed the library as before, using this command:
curl https://get.pimoroni.com/envirophat | bash

from this website:
https://learn.pimoroni.com/article/getting-started-with-enviro-phat

I then copied over my working python file (named envirophat2.py) from the old sd card but when i run it I get this error:
mars@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 envirophat2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mars/Desktop/envirophat2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from envirophat import light, motion, weather, leds
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/envirophat/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .i2c_bus import bus
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/envirophat/i2c_bus.py", line 20, in <module>
    bus = smbus.SMBus(1)

which is the same error I get when running even the simplest of examples from that website:
from envirophat import light

when I install the library I even get this:
Checking environment...
Updating apt indexes...
.....................

Checking hardware requirements...

Checking for packages required for GPIO control...
raspi-gpio is already installed
RPi.GPIO installed and up-to-date

I2C already enabled

Checking packages required by I2C interface...
Python 2 smbus installed and up-to-date
Python 3 smbus installed and up-to-date

and eventually. I even get this:
The examples directory already exists on your system!
We've backed them up as examples-backup, just in case you've changed anything!

Resources for your Enviro pHAT were copied to
/home/mars/Pimoroni/envirophat

All done. Enjoy your Enviro pHAT!

So it seems the installation works, but something is off because it keeps tryna look for stuff in python3.9.
EDIT
Running this apt command as suggested I get no errors:
mars@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt install python3-envirophat
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
python3-envirophat is already the newest version (1.0.0).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 42 not upgraded.

asd
How do i fix this?

Python 3.9(.2) is the default on bullseye, so when you use python3 envirophat2.py that's what python3 refers to.   You obviously have a (broken? old?) version of envirophat in /usr/local, and modules are resolving following a default set of paths which includes that (see python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)". There's nothing weird going on.  Using a venv would help sort your problems.

The issue is that the default path list python uses to look for packages prioritizes the /usr/local installation.  This is on 32-bit bullseye:
> python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"

['', '/usr/lib/python39.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.9', '/usr/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload', 
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Those are checked in that order.  We know from the error you have a (broken) install in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages (the 2nd last path), but you also have the one from the distro installed via apt.  That will be in /usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/, the last path in the list. You can confirm this with ls  /usr/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/envirophat.
The easiest thing to do is just delete the old one:
sudo rm -fr /usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/envirophat

As far as I'm aware (I copy modules in and out of system paths sometimes), python doesn't use a registry or cache beyond that, so when the install directory is gone the module (at that location) is cleanly gone.
As mentioned several times, you may want to look into using a venv for this to avoid these kinds of problems.  It's beyond the scope of this site to teach people python programming in depth, but there are various guides to this already online -- it is no different on a Pi than any other linux system, you could start with the guide on docs.python.org.

It is "look(ing) for stuff in python3.9" because that is where distribution packages are normally installed.
It is unclear what the command you executed would actually do but presumably installed something into your user environment at /home/mars/Pimoroni/envirophat. To use you would need to modify the python path (unless the download does this).
You would be better to install the system version with sudo apt install python3-envirophat. This would also correctly install dependencies.
You should probably uninstall the user version, but unless it has better instructions on how you might be better to restore your backup first.
The page you linked seems rather old!

when i run that python3-envirophat I get that I already have the newest version available 1.0.0.   When you say uninstall the user version, what do you mean and where can I read up on how to do that?

The instructions you linked were remarkably uninformative but SHOULD contain uninstall instructions. It is probably in /usr/local/lib/python3 and you could just delete. The correct version installed by apt would be in /usr/lib/python3. If both are installed the version in local would be used.

the directory structure doesnt contain python3; only pypy2.7  & python3.9

There should be a link from python3 to 3.9 but they are the same. Note in current OS (which has python3.11) pip no longer installs in local but requires a virtual environment - to avoid the hassle you are currently experiencing.

ok, thanks.  could you point me in the direction of where i can learn to do that?

I am not sure what "that" you are asking about. Virtual environments have been part of python for years and is documented on the python site. It has only come to prominence because Bookworm refuses to allow pip to install to system directories. Your problem came about by following a poorly documented script which is probably out of date. You probably should check with the author if they have updated their process. Frankly I wouldn't run any script which installs stuff without studying it.

You should ALWAYS check if there is an apt installation for any program before attempting installation apt correctly installs system code.

See http://rptl.io/venv for Pi documentation on venv

It turns out i2c was not enabled despite being installed according to the scripts.  Once enabled with:
sudo raspi-config nonint do_i2c 0

all went smoothly.
THanks to all
